# Whose Community Bulletin?

Tags: discussion

I'd assume the use of “community” on the *French Language* website refers to the *French Language* community. However, some blogs posts from other wild lands of the SE empire regularly make their way to its “Bulletin”.

[The return of CodingHorror](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/08/podcast-51-the-return-of-codinghorror) is maybe relevant to me and a few others who have been active in other parts of the empire, but I don't think that it is of special interest to most *French Language* users or leachers… who might not even have a clue, after reading the blog post, of what kind of horror has come back.

On the other hand, I can imagine a few blog posts form different sources to be relevant. For example would-be “meta” related blog posts from other language sites, or maybe posts from linguistics. Maybe from the TeX SE blog, concerning French typography, etc.

Why not to put acceptance of any kind of external blog posts to our Bulletin on a vote somehow?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

The community bulletin displays up to four items, with decreasing priority:

- Moderator elections (not applicable as long as the site is in beta).
- Events registered by moderators, and events in the site's main chat room.
- [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) meta posts.
- Other [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) meta posts, selected automatically (based on criteria such as views, score and age — see [How is the contents of the Community Bulletin determined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-is-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined/130893#130893) and [What formula should be used to determine “hot” questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) for the precise rules). Meta posts from the [main Stack Exchange meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) may also appear.
- Blog posts from the site's blog if the site has one, from the [official Stack Exchange blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/) otherwise.

See [the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-is-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined) for the precise selection rules.

Blog posts from the main Stack Exchange site that [have the `stackoverflow` tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171278/dont-display-stackoverflow-tagged-blog-posts-on-community-bulletins-network-w) are excluded. The [Return of CodingHorror](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/08/podcast-51-the-return-of-codinghorror/) post doesn't have this tag. It isn't just about CodingHorror (which is of interest to programmers), generic Stack Exchange topics were also discussed, such as the new Android app and the new [Space](https://space.stackexchange.com/) site.

There is no provision to feature blog posts from another site. Feeding one other site's blog should be doable, but I don't know that it is desirable: after all, it's the Linguistics/TeX/… blog, most posts would be as irrelevant here as the SO blog posts. Filtering interesting posts only sounds complex. You can post interesting links in the chat room — but I admit that it gives even less visibility than the chat room.

There's no way for moderators to push a link onto the bulletin, except for events (which have specific start and end times). That would be nice.

---

Le panneau d'affichage contient jusqu'à quatre entrées, avec par priorité décroissante :

- Les élections de modérateurs en cours (sans objet tant que le site est en bêta).
- Les évènements prochains sur le [salon de clavardage principal du site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1098/chez-cosette), et ceux créés par un modérateur sur un autre salon de clavardage associé au site.
- Des questions sur méta avec l'étiquette [featured](/questions/tagged/featured).
- D'autres questions sur méta avec l'étiquette [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), choisis en fonction de critères tels que le nombre de vues, le score et l'âge (voir [How is the contents of the Community Bulletin determined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-is-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined/130893#130893) et [What formula should be used to determine “hot” questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) pour les règles exactes)). Des questions du [site méta principal de Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) peuvent également apparaître.
- Des messages du blog associé au site, ou en son absence du [blog de Stack Overflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/).

Voir [the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-is-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined) pour des règles plus détaillées.

Il n'est pas possible d'y afficher des messages de blog d'autres sites. Cela devrait être techniquement faisable, mais je ne vois pas vraiment l'intérêt : ce seraient des messages concernant la linguistique, TeX, … qui seraient pour la plupart tout autant hors-sujet. Filtrer les messages de blog intéressants me paraît compliqué. Chacun peut poster des liens qu'il juge intéressant dans le salon de clavardage, mais j'admet que cela ne leur donne pas beaucoup de visibilité.

Les modérateurs ne peuvent pas ajouter un lien de leur choix au panneau, à part les évènements du salon (qui ont des heures précises de début et de fin). C'est dommage.

Comment: So let's have [this meta question](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/530/can-we-have-a-french-user-interface) in the community bulletin. Ça serait bien si elle avait 3,640 upvotes !